# Finding the sum of even factorials

Tags: python

```
    def factorial(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * factorial (n-1)


    def sum_even_factorials(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        elif n % 2 == 0 and n>=0:
            total = 0
            return total + sum(factorial(n))
            n = n - 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I defined the factorial function then proceeded to find the sum of even factorials.

Comment: You're resetting `total` to zero on each call. Also, `n = n - 1` is unreachable.

Comment: What *are* you doing wrong? What is actually not going as expected with your code?

Comment: you probably didn't intend to call the built-in sum.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be looping on the range, and sum only if the number is even:

```
def sum_even_factorials(n):
  total = 0
  for i in range(n + 1): # or just n, depending on the requirements 
    if i % 2 == 0:
      total = total + factorial(i)

  return total
```

You can't apply `sum` on an `int` (it's an error).

Comment: Slightly irrelevant for this question, but when would one use n in the range? Should it not always be (n+1) so as to cover the entire range up till n? Could you give me some better examples?

Comment: Another thing is, how should I improve on my code? As you can see, I understand conceptually what is going on, but I somehow have problems organising them in order and writing down the code in a systematic manner. Should i always start with the total, or should i start with the conditions? Any advice to get better?

Comment: @statsguy21 If you want to print numbers from `0-9`, given `n = 10`, you do `range(n)`. Regarding your second question, practicing, reading tutorials and making mistakes is the best way you can improve yourself. Just keep doing it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a range and a step size of 2. So something like this

```
import math

 def sum_of_even_factorials(n):
    ans = 0
    #check if number is even
    if(n%2==0):
        #loop through the range of 0 - n with step size of 2
        for i in range(0,n+2,2):
            #find the factorial of i at each step and add to answer
                ans = math.factorial(i) + ans
        return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Builtin sum function is for lists not for int , Your code is absolutely fine but  don't use sum , it will create an error (Because you do not have number of elements to iterate through)

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Your code will look like :

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial (n-1)


def sum_even_factorials(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n>=0:
        total = 0
        return total + factorial(n)
        n = n - 1
```